# jquery promise.done is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

From a simple jquery ajax call, I am returning a promise object to be handled by caller.

```
chkSession: function() {
    if (session == undefined)
        session = new Entities.Session({});                 

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        /* if no session cookie, return false */
        if (session.id === undefined) { 
            deferred.resolveWith(this, {result: -1});
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        /* validate the session with server */
        session.fetch({
            complete: function() {
                deferred.resolveWith(this, {result: this.result});
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

somewhere else in the calling code...,

```
var promise = this.chkSession();
promise.done(function() { ... });
```

but the above code fails with error **Uncaught TypeError: promise.done is not a function**

If I try to print the 'promise' object in the caller context, it is not undefined, but points to a function:

- function (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}

What am I doing wrong here?  I saw similar issue posted [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12946) as a ticket in jquery site, but this was resolved as *works for me*.

I tried using jquery 1.11.1 and 2.1.4.  both versions show the same problem.

Comment: If you don't get in to your `if` condition, you're not returning a promise.  Could be the issue

Comment: @Tom: That would throw a different error though (assuming the function returns `undefined` it that case).

Comment: methinks you want to `return deferred.promise()`, not `return deferred.promise`.

Comment: i debugged n saw that it's calling the code for var deferred... line and returning correctly.  The "if ..." line is only creating a singleton session object if it doesn't exist.

Comment: got it. My mistake was that I wasn't calling deferred.promise(). Omitted the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credits to @roippi for pointing out the syntactical mistake.

It should have been

```
return deferred.promise();
```

instead of

```
return deferred.promise;
```

missing parantheses, after 'promise'.